# Effects of data directory being on same partition as windows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

If the database directory is on the same partition as windows can it cause my operating system be less responsive? Will the performance degradation of the OS be extensive or barely noticeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big issue would be to make sure to keep the data files (which are dominated by random I/O) on a separate disk (and preferably different controller, too) from the log files (which have only sequential writes, for the most part). Mixing those random I/O with the constant sequential writing can be quite bad for performance.

And yes - I don't have any numbers to back it up, but I would believe having the OS and SQL Server data files on the same disk would cause performance to suffer - you will have two distinct sets of operations (OS and SQL Server) accessing the same disk in two separate, random I/O kind of patterns - certainly not ideal!

A commonly seen best practice for low-end SQL Server systems would be three disks:

- one for the OS and tools
- one for your data
- one for your logs

Comment: I always wondered why the option for log file location was given so prominently :)